# Laravel slack logging working locally, not in production

Tags: laravel, localhost, production-environment, slack

I have set up the slack logging using the [docs](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/logging) and it works fine. Now I've started deployment and it doesn't work anymore.

Biggest difference between the two is in the .env file (environment = local/production, debug = true/false).

Can anyone point me in the right direction? Or at least give a hint on how to go about debugging this?

Comment: Dump out `config('logging.channels.slack')` to make sure it matches your expectations

Comment: I did and it shows me the env variable I saved for my webhook. and the rest of my settings from logging.php

Comment: Well, if the url is set correctly, it'd be pretty odd for it not to work.  If you have access to tinker, see if you can generate any errors: `Log::channel('slack')->info('Something happened!');`

Comment: Thank you, that set me on the right track... I needed to specify the slack channel in production for some reason.

Comment: What does `config('logging.default')` and `config('logging.channels.stack')` output?

Comment: Okay okay... silly me.. I forgot to artisan config:cache and the the channel was still set to just 'single'. After the clearing the cache it worked.